# list a linux directory after erasing it

Tags: linux, filesystems

I'm wondering if it's possible to list the content of a directory in linux after erasing it and recreating.

Explanation: I'm on a terminal in this particular directory. From another terminal, I erase it and recreate it and put some content inside. If I list this directory from the first terminal, it appears as empty. I need to `cd ..` and enter inside again to list it's content.

Is there another method who doesn't need to do that?

Comment: I think this is because the first session has the directory open... by file handle not by name.

Comment: Yes, that is right. Under Linux, you can use files and directories even when they are deleted as long as they are opened. This could be explained in a general form (POSIX functions), but some people thought this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way, as far as I know, is to *cd* in it again. However, you can do it with one simple command. Select which one you like the most between the following four

```
cd ${PWD}
cd $PWD
cd $(pwd)
cd `pwd`
```

You can also add to your *~/.bashrc* an alias like this:

```
alias refresh_dir="cd \$PWD"
```

and then call the *refresh_dir* command directly

Comment: What's with all the whitespace?

Comment: Which whitespaces?

Answer (score 0):

Would `ls ../{directory-name}` work? So if the directory was called "test", and you were inside it, you'd use the command `ls ../test/`.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You can, of course,

```
 cd "$PWD"
```

which is a quicker way in a sense.

Some shells might not cache the inode for the current working directory, but I have a sneaking suspicion that POSIX might require shells to. If you think about it, having the shell do this automatically might result in unintended loss of data (because a program/script might go and modify stuff in a directory that *wasn't strictly it's working directory to begin with*).

Also look at bash [PROMPT_COMMAND](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html) for a hint on how to automate it, of you find yourself having to type `cd "$PWD"` more than you like

Answer (score 0):

terminal 1:

```
mkdir dir/
cd dir/
touch foo/
ls
```

terminal 2:

```
rm -r dir/
mkdir dir/
touch dir/bar
```

terminal 1:

```
cd `pwd`
ls
```